# opencart: How to integrate sagepay test account?

Tags: php, opencart, opayo

I am developing a website on opencart. I want to integrate sagepay account on that website.

But for testing phase I want to create a test account on sagepay and then integrate it on opencart.

So I have two questions:

1. How to create test account on sagepay?
2. How to integrate test account of sagepay on opencart?

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

1. To create a Test Account you'd need to apply for one via [here](https://support.sagepay.com/apply/default.aspx?PartnerID=E511AF91-E4A0-42DE-80B0-09C981A3FB61) if using Opencart. A Test account is only provided once you have submitted your application, whilst your merchant number is being validated with your merchant bank.
2. Can't answer how but can confirm the testing requirements for Sage Pay which you'll need to follow which can be found [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/test-your-integration) once you have your test account.

Integration documents are available [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document) which will help you with your integration once you have decided on whether you are using web to server (Form), server to server (Server) or hosting everything on your site (Direct).

There is the [Simulator](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/sage-pay-simulator) for pretesting before get a Test account for v2.23 integration only. Integration documents on Sage Pay website are v3.00.